# ConsoliBYTE QuickBooks PHP DevKit: Two queues, same DSN, auto run conflicts

Tags: php, quickbooks

Before I start changing code, here is what our QWC Application entries do...

1. `enqueue` online orders at `HOOK_LOGINSUCCESS` via `QUICKBOOKS_ADD_CUSTOMER`, `QUICKBOOKS_ADD_INVOICE`, and `QUICKBOOKS_ADD_RECEIVEPAYMENT` (`ID` *order_number*)
2. `enqueue` CSV data at different `HOOK_LOGINSUCCESS` via `QUICKBOOKS_ADD_SALESORDER` (`ID` *filename*)

Both queues use the same dsn and work fine on manual or when auto-run individually. When both tasks are auto-run and eventually execute during the same minute (unavoidable), the function mapping from #1 somehow gets mixed in with those from #2.

We noticed this problem when error **No registered functions for action: CustomerAdd** was thrown during #2 but the `ID` was from #1. So it looks like #2 established the connection, but #1 sent requests/responses during the "same minute" conflict.

We now have both tasks scheduled to **Auto-run** at different **Every _ Min** intervals (24 and 25) so conflicts are less frequent, but would rather have no conflict at all.

I am thinking `deny_concurrent_logins` (and/or `deny_reallyfast_logins`) handler options should keep them from running at the same time, but want to be sure before making "maybe" changes to a busy online store.

Note: I know we can avoid this by using a different `dsn` for each task, but cannot imagine that is necessary.

Comment: Note: Task #2 does not require `QUICKBOOKS_ADD_CUSTOMER` since the customer name is hard-coded into `SalesOrderAddRq` (always the same customer).

Comment: You didn't post any code, so this isn't really possible to answer. But, my guess would be that you're not using two separate USERNAMES to connect, and you probably should be.

Comment: Looks like running task #2 as a different username may have resolved the queue conflict. Will know for sure within 24 hours while both auto-run. Add the suggestion as an answer and we can probably mark it accepted sometime tomorrow :)

Comment: Even with a different username for #2, the queue from #1 somehow fires after #2 establishes the initial connection. While watching the log, we saw the initial connection (using task #2 methods) but the ticket ended up being assigned to the task #1 username (fires at the same time as task #2). Guessing it's due to the asynchronous nature of QWC and something we are either missing or was unexpected in the DevKit. **Sledgehammer:** We added another DB to store the #2 queue to get _around_ the issue.

Comment: It's something you're missing or messed up. But you need to post your code so we can actually help you.

Comment: I'd be happy to show _you_ the code privately, but we cannot post code from this client's system in public forum. Email **info at mavelo dot com** if you want to have a look. PS: We tried contacting many times (using different methods, outside of SO) to purchase an integration before writing our own solution with your library ;)